# C# Validation for specific input

Tags: c#, validation

I'm kinda new to this thread, but in short summary i'm having trouble with a small validation issue. Basically, i'm attempting to make a simple validation program that will collect a user's input and then determine if the input is valid in terms of, input being correctly implemented, the number being positive, and the number having to be either `0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5`.

The overall program runs, but the issue i'm facing is every form of input is deemed an error, thus displaying my error statement, even if it is a valid input like 5 for example. I feel like there is a small mistake,i have made that is causing this, So is there any suggestions?

```
 int user_input;
 int count = 0;
 do
 {
    Console.Write("\n\nUser Input:"

    if ((int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out user_input) == false)||(user_input < 0 || user_input != 0 ||user_input != 1 || user_input != 2
                || user_input != 3 || user_input != 4 || user_input != 5)) 
    {

       Console.WriteLine("Error : the action entered is not a valid number.");
       count = 0;
    }
    else
       count = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is because you use [OR operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).
For example user print `3`. In your statements one condition return `false` (`input != 3`), but all others return `true`.. That's why you always go into `if condition`..

You can use AND operator, but I can recommend you to simplify your condition. It will be more understandable and readable:

```
var count = 0;
do
{
   Console.Write("\n\nUser Input:");

   int user_input;
   if ((int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out user_input) == false) || (user_input < 0 || user_input > 5))
   {

      Console.WriteLine("Error : the action entered is not a valid number.");
      count = 0;
   }
   else
      count = 1;
} 
while (count != 1);
```

Comment: Just one language nitpick: It's not necessarily a mistake to use the OR operator, though it is a mistake to *misuse* the OR operator.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, implemented perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You already got an answer about the problem with predicate logic. But you can even more simplify with linq like:

```
var count = (new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5"}).Contains(Console.ReadLine()) ? 1 : 0;
```